# kNN Consistently Overusing One Label

Tags: machine-learning, classification, knn, confusion-matrix

I am using a kNN to do some classification of labeled images. After my classification is done, I am outputting a confusion matrix. I noticed that one label, `bottle` was being applied incorrectly more often.[image: bottle_matrix]

I removed the label and tested again, but then noticed that another label, `shoe` was being applied incorrectly, but was fine last time.[image]

There should be no normalization, so I'm unsure what is causing this behavior. Testing showed it continued no matter how many labels I removed.
Not totally sure how much code to post, so I'll put some things that should be relevant and pastebin the rest.

```
def confusionMatrix(classifier, train_DS_X, train_DS_y, test_DS_X, test_DS_y):
    # Will output a confusion matrix graph for the predicion
    y_pred = classifier.fit(train_DS_X, train_DS_y).predict(test_DS_X)
    labels = set(set(train_DS_y) | set(test_DS_y))

    def plot_confusion_matrix(cm, title='Confusion matrix', cmap=plt.cm.Blues):
        plt.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
        plt.title(title)
        plt.colorbar()
        tick_marks = np.arange(len(labels))
        plt.xticks(tick_marks, labels, rotation=45)
        plt.yticks(tick_marks, labels)
        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.ylabel('True label')
        plt.xlabel('Predicted label')

    # Compute confusion matrix
    cm = confusion_matrix(test_DS_y , y_pred)
    np.set_printoptions(precision=2)
    print('Confusion matrix, without normalization')
    #print(cm)
    plt.figure()
    plot_confusion_matrix(cm)

    # Normalize the confusion matrix by row (i.e by the number of samples
    # in each class)
    cm_normalized = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
    print('Normalized confusion matrix')
    #print(cm_normalized)
    plt.figure()
    plot_confusion_matrix(cm_normalized, title='Normalized confusion matrix')

    plt.show()
```

Relevant Code from Main Function:

```
# Select training and test data
    PCA = decomposition.PCA(n_components=.95)
    zscorer = ZScoreMapper(param_est=('targets', ['rest']), auto_train=False)
    DS = getVoxels (1, .5)
    train_DS = DS[0]
    test_DS = DS[1]

    # Apply PCA and ZScoring
    train_DS = processVoxels(train_DS, True, zscorer, PCA)
    test_DS = processVoxels(test_DS, False, zscorer, PCA)
    print 3*"\n"

    # Select the desired features
    # If selecting samples or PCA, that must be the only feature
    featuresOfInterest = ['pca']
    trainDSFeat = selectFeatures(train_DS, featuresOfInterest)
    testDSFeat = selectFeatures(test_DS, featuresOfInterest)
    train_DS_X = trainDSFeat[0]
    train_DS_y = trainDSFeat[1]
    test_DS_X = testDSFeat[0]
    test_DS_y = testDSFeat[1]


    # Optimization of neighbors
    # Naively searches for local max starting at numNeighbors
    lastScore = 0
    lastNeightbors = 1
    score = .0000001
    numNeighbors = 5
    while score > lastScore:
        lastScore = score
        lastNeighbors = numNeighbors
        numNeighbors += 1
        #Classification
        neigh = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=numNeighbors, weights='distance')
        neigh.fit(train_DS_X, train_DS_y)

        #Testing
        score = neigh.score(test_DS_X,test_DS_y )

    # Confusion Matrix Output
    neigh = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=lastNeighbors, weights='distance')
    confusionMatrix(neigh, train_DS_X, train_DS_y, test_DS_X, test_DS_y)
```

Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/U7yTs3vs

Comment: what is distribution of labels? How many of each?

Comment: train_ds: `{'rest': 256, 'scrambledpix': 70, 'bottle': 66, 'chair': 61, 'scissors': 59, 'face': 57, 'house': 55, 'cat': 54, 'shoe': 48}`


test_ds: `{'rest': 248, 'shoe': 68, 'cat': 65, 'house': 63, 'scissors': 61, 'face': 61, 'chair': 57, 'bottle': 53, 'scrambledpix': 49}`

Comment: you have errors somewhere. Total amount of bottle instances is 119, and you confusion matrix shows about 250 of correct classifications of bottle instances.

Comment: it also looks like incorrect usage of PCA, it looks like you fit it independently to train and test, while you should fit it only once, and later use it. There are probably more such errors in the "hidden" part of the code.

Comment: I actually only fit on one, you can see if you look at the paste at the bottom of my post. Thanks regarding the counts! I'll try debugging where the extras are coming from, also I realized I should be seeding my random splitting for test and training while I debug. I'll post back later if I figure it out.

Comment: oh, right you pass the "false" flag, so PCA is ok, sorry for false alarm.

Comment: Also, I think I figured out the issue, and it's simple -_-. I think the order of my labels on the Confusion Matrix is wrong, that bottle condition looks like it should be rest. Can you see what is wrong there?

Comment: My basic issue is that I don't know the logic behind scikit-learn's ordering on the confusion matrix data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in part the result of my axis being mislabeled, when I thought I was removing the faulty label I was in actuality just removing a random label, meaning the faulty data was still being analyzed. Fixing the axis and removing the faulty label which was actually `rest` yielded:
[image]

The code I changed is:
`cm = confusion_matrix(test_DS_y , y_pred, labels)`

Basically I manually set the ordering based on my list of ordered labels.